# Which Java class is compatible with python Pandas DataFrame when using DJL(Deep Java Library)?

Tags: java, pandas, spring-boot, dataframe, djl

I'm trying to import Python Tensorflow custom model to `spring-boot` using `DJL Tensorflow`, and the model gets `Pandas DataFrame` as both input and output.

I'm wondering if there is any particular table or dataFrame class that is applicable for Criteria<I, O> and ZooModel<I, O> since there is only Image class from `ai.djl.modality.cv.Image` in example codes.

If there is, is the class compatible with `Pandas DataFrame`? There are some codes that I wrote and error messages below.

I've already tried `tablesaw.api.Table` and `apache.spark.sql.Dataset` but it did not work. If you know any information about it, please let me know.

**conditions**

- Input class `I` and Output class `O` should be equivalent to `Pandas DataFrame`
- This class should be applicable for `Criteria<I, O>` and `ZooModel<I, O>`

**codes**

```
Criteria<I, O> criteria = Criteria.builder()
                 .setTypes(I.class, O.class) // defines input and output data type
                 .optModelUrls("../model/mlpDemo/") // search models in specified path
                 .build();
        
try (ZooModel<I, O> model = criteria.loadModel(); 
        Predictor<I, O> predictor = model.newPredictor();) {
    O result = predictor.predict(dataFrame); // here should be loaded dataFrame
    System.out.print(result);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**error messages**

```
ai.djl.repository.zoo.ModelNotFoundException: No matching model with specified Input/Output type found.
    at ai.djl.repository.zoo.Criteria.loadModel(Criteria.java:186)
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:69)
Caused by: ai.djl.repository.zoo.ModelNotFoundException: No matching default translator found. The valid input and output classes are: 
    (ai.djl.ndarray.NDList, ai.djl.ndarray.NDList)

    at ai.djl.repository.zoo.BaseModelLoader.loadModel(BaseModelLoader.java:97)
    at ai.djl.repository.zoo.Criteria.loadModel(Criteria.java:174)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: I found that I should use **NDList**, and Tensorflow-engine converts it automatically to **TfNDArray** inside

Answer (score 1):

You need create your own `Translator` to convert `DataFrame` into `NDList`:

```
    class MyTranslator implements NoBatchifyTranslator<DataFrame, Classifcations> {

        @Override
        public NDList processInput(TranslatorContext ctx, DataFrame input) {
            // convert DataFrame columns into NDArrays
            NDArray col1 = ...
            NDArray col2 = ...
            return new NDList(col1, col2);
        }

        /** {@inheritDoc} */
        @Override
        public Classifications processOutput(TranslatorContext ctx, NDList list) {
            // implement your post processing
            return new Classifications();
        }
    }
```